# How to transfer one-to-many data from a database to a template in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

There are many tables. One characterizes the sliders, the other contains information inside these sliders. My task is to transfer all values from tables into one template. That is, when choosing the desired slider from the possible, we were given relevant information.

What has been done:

1. Tables were connected by a one-to-many method.

Main model

```
class AdminSlider extends Model
{

public function aboutUs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AboutUs');
    }

public function mainSlider()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MainSlider');
}
}
```

Dependent models looks like

```
class MainSlider extends Model
{
    public function adminSlider()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AdminSlider', 'slider_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

2. Was created the variable which is working with template in controller

```
    public function index()
     {   
        $adminSlidersItems = $this->getSliderInfo();

    $sliderInfo = view('admin.adminEditText')->with('sliderInfo',$adminSlidersItems)->render();
    $this->vars = array_add($this->vars, 'sliderInfo', $sliderInfo);

    return $this->renderOutput();
  }   

 public function getSliderInfo() {

        $sliderInfoItems = $this->as_rep->get();

        return $sliderInfoItems;  
     }
```

When I looked into variable admin in controller I saw Collection

```
{#230 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => AdminSlider {#231 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "admin_sliders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "Main Slider"
        "path" => "http://jinol/admin/sliders/mainslider"
        "img" => "mainslider.jpg"
        "alias" => "mainslider"
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => AdminSlider {#232 ▶}
    2 => AdminSlider {#233 ▶}
    3 => AdminSlider {#234 ▶}
    4 => AdminSlider {#235 ▶}
    5 => AdminSlider {#236 ▶}
  ]
}
```

template.layout

```
@extends('admin.site')

@section('admin.adminNavigation')
    {!! $adminNavigation !!}
@endsection

@section('admin.adminEditText')
    {!! $sliderInfo !!}
@endsection
```

3. Define our variables in template.

```
@if(count ($sliderInfo) > 0) <br>
    <div id="content-page" class="content group"><br>
        @foreach($sliderInfo as $info)<br>
            <tr><br>
             <td class="align-left">{{$info->adminSlider->id}}</td><br>
            </tr><br>   
        @endforeach<br> 
    </div><br>
@endif
```

4. In the end of this I have got an error.

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
>   W:\domains\jinol\resources\views\admin\adminEditText.blade.php).

How can I find my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$info->adminSlider['id']
```

insted of

```
$info->adminSlider->id
```

i think it will be solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for help, error has gone. But page does not recieve any data from db now.

Comment: make sure that your data was fetch correctly.

maybe your slider id have not in admin slider table

Comment: Hmm... I have not it. I thought that if I did relations one to many I could bind id from Admin Slider table with slider_id which were placed in anoter tables

Answer (score 0):

In your controller change:

```
public function index()
 {   
    $adminSlidersItems = $this->getSliderInfo();

$sliderInfo = view('admin.adminEditText')->with('sliderInfo',$adminSlidersItems)->render();
  $this->vars = array_add($this->vars, 'sliderInfo', $sliderInfo);

  return $this->renderOutput();
}
```

To:

```
public function index()
{   
    $adminSlidersItems = $this->getSliderInfo();

    return view('admin.adminEditText', ['sliderInfo' => $adminSlidersItems]);
}
```

In your view change

```
<td class="align-left">{{$info->adminSlider->id}}</td><br>
```

To

```
<td class="align-left">{{optional($info->adminSlider)->id}}</td><br>
```

Apparently, not all of your $sliderInfo's have a ->adminSlider defined and you get an error when trying to access id on it when it's set to null.  The optional helper will only try to access the id when ->adminSlider is not null.

Comment: It look's like that. Thank you for help, error has gone. But page does not recieve any data from db now.

Comment: try `{{dd($sliderInfo)}}` at the top of your view file to see what you're actually passing to it

Comment: Did you try it from the view?  I don't think you're passing the variables into the view correctly.

Comment: But it is my $sliderInfoItems which works with model. I added it  to variable  $sliderInfo and rendered. If i ll take dd from $sliderInfo it would be unreadeble because i have template in this variable

Comment: If I take simple data from the independant table I have normal result.  But now i take data from connecting tables. May be i have done something wrong in model

Comment: Keep in mind you should be able to dump any variables that your view is using from your view.  I have updated my answer with a different way to pass the variable to the view.

Comment: thank you for help but page is still empty : (
May i have some problem with models?